# Merging or returning values by condition from multiple tables to the one table in PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am newbye in coding. Could someone help with the task please.
I need to return values from two tables by condition to the one single table.
Let's say
TABLE 1:

***`Name of Product`***    ***`QTY`***        ***`TYPE`***         
`Iphone X`                 `9`     `Smartphone`   
`HP`                       `7`      `LAPTOP`       
`Galaxy S20`               `8`     `Smartphone`   
`MAC Pro`                  `6`      `LAPTOP`

TABLE 2:

***`BRANDS`***         ***`SEGMENT`***  
`HP`                `GOLD`     
`MAC Pro`          `PREMIUM`

TABLE 3:

***`BRANDS`***         ***`SEGMENT`***  
`Iphone X`       `PREMIUM`  
`Galaxy S20`    `GOLD`

So i need  the result something like this below.
TABLE 1 result:

***`Name of Product`***    ***`QTY`***        ***`TYPE`***            ***`SEGMENT`***         
`Iphone X`                 `9`     `Smartphone`     `PREMIUM`         
`HP`                       `7`      `LAPTOP`         `GOLD`            
`Galaxy S20`               `8`     `Smartphone`     `GOLD`            
`MAC Pro`                  `6`      `LAPTOP`         `PREMIUM`

Thanks in advance!!